# Creating laravel project with docker

Tags: laravel, docker

when i run ( curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash )
for creating a project in laravel download wont finish it show below

Unable to find image 'laravelsail/php81-composer:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from laravelsail/php81-composer
eff15d958d66: Downloading  26.83MB/31.37MB
933427dc39f7: Download complete
35bb08dc7ee2: Downloading  9.059MB/91.6MB
58a3f26800d7: Download complete
28803bfad74c: Downloading  4.303MB/12.06MB
341a482d0bd3: Waiting
03c4148389b1: Waiting
fa3a9bfc7793: Waiting
024907232600: Waiting
df5987d70de6: Waiting
e2a72a518bd8: Waiting
b1ba689993c8: Waiting
3bd142ab0b85: Waiting
872fe34989f0: Waiting

In addition,i use proton vpn because of the sanctions of my country
what should i do?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the VPN. Could you try to disable it?

Comment: i have tried, not working